# Building a net40 project in VisualStudio 2022

Tags: .net-4.0

A Windows update trashed my computer so I've had to reinstall from scratch.

We have some projects that multi-target `net40`

```
<TargetFrameworks>net40;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

which were building just fine (and they build in the Azure pipeline) but now I can't get them to build locally.

My old machine was originally win10 with VisualStudio 2017, 2019, and 2022, but so far on the rebuilt machine I only have 2022.

The projects won't build, saying

```
error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

I guess this means I have to install an SDK pack?

I've tried 4.6.2 and 4.6.1 which are available through the VisualStudio installer, and 4.5 (`NDP452-KB2901951-x86-x64-DevPack.exe` from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net452-developer-pack-offline-installer) which is not, and *Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4* from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/
but still no joy.

Any idea what I need to do to get it to build again?

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to install VisualStudio2017 with `net40`.